# Sharepoint 2013 foundation database compatibility

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, database

The company I am working for is considering updating to Sql server 2019, from reading the documentation, it says that the highest version that 2013 foundation works with is 2016. My question is, can I run a database in 2016 compatibility mode on 2019 and have Sharepoint foundation 2013 work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SharePoint 2013 only supports up to SQL Server 2016.

Comment: so its not about the database compatibility at all then?

Comment: For 2013, that is correct. For 2016+, Microsoft changed the stance to supporting any version of SQL that is compatible with a specific schema level. For 2016, compat level 110; for 2019, compat level 130.

Comment: man thats really lame. thanks for the clarification.